# Regex.Split on "() " and "?"

Tags: c#, regex

```
myString= "First?Second Third";    
String[] result = Regex.Split(myString, @"( )\?");
```

Should result:
First,
Second,
Third

What am I missing? (I also need brackets to split on for something else)

Comment: You told us what you expected but not what you get.

Comment: Why regex at all? `String[] result = myString.Split(' ', '?');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess with `( )`, you meant whitespace. You don't need any capturing group there. Just use alteration, or a character class:

```
String[] result = Regex.Split(myString, @"\s|\?");

// OR
String[] result = Regex.Split(myString, @"[\s?]");
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about using "|" for splitting. I changed it to @"\?|( )" so it keeps the space as separate entry.

Answer (score 3):

Using string methods:

```
myString= "First?Second Third";
String[] result = myString.Split(' ','?');
```

Comment: Thanks. I did forget to mention that I needed space characters to be kept as separate entries in array, so I ended up using Regex. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do with the quotes. Remember that in C# parenthesis are used to denote a logical group in your regular expression, they do not escape a space. Rather you want to split on an explicit set of characters, which is denoted by brackets []. You should use the following pattern to split:

```
String[] result = Regex.Split(myString, @"[\?\s]");
```

Note that \? is an escaped space (as you had in your original). White-space characters are escaped as \s. Thus, my solution is essentially saying to separate the string on any of the explicitly indicated characters (based on the []) and lists those characters as ? (escaped as \?) and " " (escaped as \s).

EDIT AFTER MORE INFO FROM OP:
I also saw, after answering this post, that you editted the top comment to say you wanted a logical grouping for the white-space, in which case I would go with:

```
String[] result = Regex.Split(myString, @"[\?(\s)]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround those chars inside `[]` to create a range of them.  `[\s\?]`  This will split on:

1. a space
2. `?`

You can use `\s` to handle "any" whitespace char.